# How to select some cells of a particular row which are not adjacent?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have `1000` rows with `100` columns.

And I want to select `2nd`  row with `6,14,56,37,87` column?

And I want to select `5th` row with `3,5,9,24` column.

Please suggest a different way to approch this ?
And with a formula?

Comment: in VBA? What are you trying to do once they're selected?

Comment: Select one cell, scroll around to the next cell, hold `Ctrl` and click the next cell, and continue like this till you get everything? The cells you need seem random enough to me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Name box at the left end of the Formula bar, check this link for a step by step tutorial

```
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-select-cells-in-excel-2010.html
```

AND

```
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/select-specific-cells-or-ranges-HP010342886.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you choose VBA as @durron597 said, it's will be like that :

```
'Specific row
Dim row As Integer
row = 2

'Specific columns (I use the letters)
Dim col As String
col = "A" & row & ",C" & row & ",E" & row & ",F" & row & ",I" & row

'Selection of the cells for the example
Range(col).Select
```